# How to build a linux based custom OS with GUI for Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: embedded-linux, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, buildroot

I am new to embedded linux, in order to learn how to build custom linux based OS from scratch I have decided to use buildroot.

I want to build a GUI based OS RaspberryPi 3B+ (or 3B) similar to that of Raspbian OS, from scratch. How do I go about this?

By googling, I was able to find a few resources that teach how to build a non-GUI based minimal OS, and could not find any for GUI based.

Looking for information and/or resources on how I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

In buildroot menuconfig running with default raspberryPi config,

Package Selection -->  Graphic libraries and applications -

Enable the following,

- X Windows System Server --> modular xorg  ( The X.Org project provides an open source implementation of the X Window)
- X.org X Window System, X11R7 --> X11R7 Applications --> xinit (gives startx command to begin GUI)
- X.org X Window System, X11R7 --> X11R7 Servers --> xorg-server (X server component)
- X.org X Window System, X11R7 --> X11R7 Drivers --> xf86-input-keyboard  (very common interface :-)
- X.org X Window System, X11R7 --> X11R7 Drivers --> xf86-input-mouse
  X.org X Window System, X11R7 --> X11R7 Drivers --> xf86-video-cirrus (Cirrus VGA is emulated in QEMU)
- X.org X Window System, X11R7 --> X11R7 Drivers --> xf86-video-fbdev (or you can use framebuffer)
- X.org X Window System, X11R7 --> X11R7 Application --> you can add some useful applications
- X.org X Window System, X11R7 --> MatchBow Window Manager (The Matchbox window manager is responsible for managing X11 client window geometry and stacking order, as well as providing decorations and controls) or any other window manager of your choice.
- X.org X Window System, X11R7 -->  rxtv (Terminal emulation program in X

Once it is built, bootup the board and run startx.

Comment: Hey @nemesis, 
Thanks for taking the time to answer the question. 

I have followed the steps you mentioned. I could not find rxtv within the buildroot that I am using (even with search option). I used xterm instead. 

After I boot the raspberry pi from the image generated, i get a blank screen after a few log messages. 

How do I navigate past this issue?